# More terse way to define Scala Stream object?

Tags: scala, stream

I have the following:

```
val notDivisibleBy2: Stream[Long] = 3L #:: 5L #:: notDivisibleBy2.tail.map(_ + 2)
println(notDivisibleBy2.take(3))
```

If `5L` is removed, a `StackOverflow` is emitted. Is there a way to have the tail calculation work so that `5L` doesn't have to be specified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are entering an infinite loop when you remove `5L` and then call the `tail` function. As you can see, the tail of `notDivisibleBy2` is `notDivisibleBy2.tail.map(_ + 2)`. You therefore need to remove both `5L` and the call to `tail`.

```
val notDivisibleBy2: Stream[Long] = 3L #:: notDivisibleBy2.map(_ + 2)
```